# Find out an algorithm that finds out if an undirected graph contains even length cycle or not using BFS?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, graph-traversal

I know how to find odd length cycles(a bipartite graph cannot have odd cycles) but I cannot manage to make an algorithm when considering even length cycles.

Comment: Should the cycle be vertex-disjoint or edge-disjoint?

Comment: Is your graph bipartite?

Comment: Do you want a simple cycle? Can the cycle repeat vertices or not?

Answer (score 1):

Construct a new graph $G'$ with the same set of vertices, and with an edge $(u,v)$ iff there is a path of length 2 from $u$ to $v$ in the original graph.  Then, check whether $G'$ has any cycles of any length.  A cycle in $G'$ corresponds to an even-length cycle in the original graph, and vice versa, so this provides a correct algorithm.  The running time is $O(|V||E|)$.

Comment: This doesn't work if the cycle needs to be simple (as it is usually the case). If $G$ is a triangle then $G' = G$, yet $G$ contains no even simple cycles. If the cycles do not need to be simple then the problem is equivalent to deciding whether there is a cycle $C$ (of any length) in $G$. If $C$ is even we are done, otherwise $C \circ C$ will be an even cycle.

Comment: @Steven good point!

Answer (score 0):

if you have no limits to complexity, try this:

For each node **v** in the graph:

1)Apply the bfs from v

2)Take the visit three and for each leaves **u** check to see if there is an edge **(u,v)** in the graphs,
if this is true then there is a cycle that hold **v** and you can count it as an *even lenght cycle* if and only if **u** has odd depth

Repeat for each node in the graph and get the number of *even lenght cycle* whit a complexity of O(|V||E|) where V is the set of nodes and E is the set of edge in the graphs.

Hope this help!

Comment: Sorry but there is a mistake in my answer,
considers **u** as any node in the tree having depth greater than 1,
now i think it can work.

Comment: Please don't use answers to try to add addendums.  Instead, revise/edit your existing answer using the 'edit' / 'suggest an improvement' link under the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do a BFS from any node, say r, construct the BFS tree.
For each edge ({u, v}) in the graph that isn't a tree edge, check whether `u.level + v.level` is even or odd.
If it's odd then the graph has an even cycle.
If it's even, then the graph has an odd cycle.

Proof:
BFS yields the shortest path between nodes r,u and r,v.
The levels of the BFS tree are equal to the distances from r.
If there is an edge between u and v that isn't a tree edge, then (r->v, v->u, u->r) forms a cycle of the length = 1 + length(r->v) + length(r->u)
We need to check whether this length is even or not.

Complexity:
O(V + E) + O(E) = O(V + E)